# Creating new rails 4 app with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler

I'm trying to create a new rails 4 app with this system setup:

OSX Mavericks

zsh

rvm 1.23.13

bundler 1.3.5

ruby 2.0.0-p247

I've installed bundler and rake in the global gemset for ruby 2

After I have installed rails 4 in the gemset I execute

rails new testapp

I get the the error:

Looks like your app's ./bin/rails is a stub that was generated by Bundler.

All of the references to this I've found are in relation to upgrading 3.2 to 4. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions in this situation.

The full sequence is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dmoulton/7270893)

Comment: What does `which -a rails` say?

Comment: /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@rails4/bin/rails
/usr/bin/rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it possible that `~/dev/eit` is already an `rails` application?

try this:

```
mkdir -p ~/dev
rails new rails4app
cd rails4app
```

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't noticed that, and it was mistakenly made to be one.